# Как избежать повторения двоеточия в даном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, двоеточие

Как избежать повтора двоеточий в предложении *"Комиссия в составе: представители ТОО: Иванов, Петров, Сидоров; представители исполнителя: Васин, Шишкин, Гусев"*?

Answer (score 1):

Не надо избегать. Нет в том нужды. Пробелы только не забывайте ставить после всех знаков препинания, после двоеточий - тоже.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, перечислить фамилии в скобках.

> Комиссия в составе: представители ТОО (Иванов, Петров, Сидоров);
>   представители исполнителя (Васин, Шишкин, Гусев).

Answer (score 0):

Если это ***обычное*** предложение (без контекста судить трудно), то могу предложить такой вариант:
Состав комиссии: Иванов, Петров, Сидоров - представители ТОО; Васин, Шишкин,  Гусев - представители исполнителя.

Если предложение является ***частью делового текста*** (договор, протокол, соглашение), то "оформление" должно быть другим:

Состав комиссии:
 Иванов, Петров, Сидоров - представители ТОО;
 Васин, Шишкин,  Гусев - представители исполнителя.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю через тире:
"Комиссия в составе: представители ТОО - Иванов, Петров, Сидоров; представители исполнителя - Васин, Шишкин, Гусев."

Answer (score 0):

Если это обычное предложение, то двоеточие вообще здесь лишнее:

**Комиссия в составе представителей ТОО Иванова, Петрова и Сидорова и представителей исполнителя Васина, Шишкина и Гусева...**

Более формализованно:

**Комиссия в составе: представители ТОО Иванов, Петров, Сидоров и представители исполнителя Васин, Шишкин, Гусев...**

Answer (score -1):

комиссия в составе представителей ТОО (Иванова, Петрова, Сидорова) и представителей исполнителя (Васина, Шишкина, Гусева)